# leiningen custom task is not a task

Tags: clojure, task, leiningen

I have the following `.lein-classpath`

```
tasks
```

then under tasks, I have

```
tasks
     > leiningen
                >foo-bar.clj
```

I then have the following contents of `foo.clj`

```
(ns leiningen.foo-bar)

(defn foo-bar [project & args]
  (println "foo"))
```

When I then run `lein foo-bar`, I receive:

```
'foo-bar' is not a task. See 'lein help'.

Did you mean this?
         foo-bar
```

Running `lein help` produces (among the general default tasks):

```
foo        Task: 'foo-bar' not found
```

I am on leiningen 2.7.1 with java 1.8.0_77

`.lein-classpath`, `tasks`, and `project.clj` are all in project root

A few more diagnostic results:

`which lein` produces: `/usr/local/bin/lein`
`~/.lein` contains no `.lein-classpath`, nor any task definitions
`/etc/leinrc` does not exist

How would I go about defining this task? And why does it "sort of" see the task (Did you mean this?...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that for all Clojure files, not just leiningen tasks, the namespace `foo-bar` must be in a file named `foo_bar.clj`, not `foo-bar.clj`.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that leiningen cannot find the task file.

Remember that .lein-classpath must be in your project root, right where your project.clj is. Also, the path is relative to your project root, so if your tasks are in `<root>/src/tasks`, you have to put `src/tasks` in your .lein-classpath.

Comment: the path is under <root>/tasks/leiningen, and .lein-classpath is in the root as is project.clj

Comment: There can be an other task defined with the same name. Check these: ~/.lein, /etc/leinrc and especially the location of lein (`which lein`) for any .lein-classpath or leinrc files.

Comment: updated question.

which lein => /usr/local/bin/lein
/etc/leinrc does not exist
~/.lein does not contain a .lein-classpath, nor any task definitions